# Variation of statistical error with adding more and more data

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, data-visualization

Suppose we will measure a quantity x from experiment and I know theoretical probability density function for that $[W(x)]$. Let's assume that we have $10^{6}$ data values.

Now at first we use theoretical probability density function $W(x)$ to generate set of discrete values which will be probabilities for equal sized bins placed along allowed range of x values.

Then we will use experimental x values to create a histogram plot for same set of bins and finally we will divide counts by total number of data values [$10^{6}$] to get probability for those bins.

We know that there will be mismatch between theoretical plot and experimental data plot. Hence we will get a mismatch area where heights on each x value of that area will be square root value of difference between theoretical binned probability and experimental binned probability.

Now comes our question.

We want to understand properties of this mismatch area with respect to adding more and more data. Surely we all know that mismatch area will going to decrease with adding more and more data. But our question is whether that degradation follows any function which is independent of particular experiment and related physics of that experiment. Our believe is that if we add x values sequentially as we get from experiment [ hence ruling out choosing x values belongs to particular portion of probability density curve first ] then properties of the graph will be-

first it will fluctuate wildly and then after addition of more and more data it will calm down and will show some respect to underlying statistical rule [if any] and our aim is to understand that particular statistical rule which will be independent of physics of the experiment [according to our believe].

Here we are attaching a relevant graph.
 [image]

Please note that in our graph there is a different drop trend after amount of data,= 5795782. This is because data belong to that portion is a particular set of x values which will belong to particular portion of probability density function curve.

Finally we repeat our question- Can we predicted a function which will define drop trend?